# Modify Javascript object by reference

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a complex query for `mongoDB`'s `aggregate` framework. It requires a component that programmatically adds an `$and` and `$or`.

This is the current structure of my object:

```
const inputObject = {
    "details.blackBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] },
    "details.blackTop": { "in": ["L","M"] },
    "details.redBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] },
    "details.redTop": { "in": ["L","M"] },
    "details.greenBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] },
    "details.greenTop": { "in": ["L","M"] }
}
```

However, for the object to be useful, I need to reformulate it so that it uses both `$or` and `$and`. The final output should look like this:

```
const outputObject = {
    "$and": [
        {
            "$or" : [
                {"details.blackBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] }},
                {"details.redBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] }},
                {"details.greenBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] }}
            ]
        },
        {
            "$or" : [
                {"details.blackTop": { "in": ["L","M"] } },
                {"details.redTop": { "in": ["L","M"] } },
                {"details.greenTop": { "in": ["L","M"] } }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the `$or` components are grouped by the `Bottom` and `Top`.

How can I turn the `inputObject` into the desired `outputObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a combination of `filter` and `map` methods:

```js
const inputObject = {
    "details.blackBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] },
    "details.blackTop": { "in": ["L","M"] },
    "details.redBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] },
    "details.redTop": { "in": ["L","M"] },
    "details.greenBottom": { "in": ["A","B","C","D"] },
    "details.greenTop": { "in": ["L","M"] }
}

const outputObject = {
    $and: ["Bottom", "Top"].map( side => ({
        $or: Object.keys(inputObject)
                   .filter( key => key.endsWith(side) )
                   .map( key => ({ [key]: inputObject[key] }) )
    }) )
};

console.log(outputObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```